# Looking for map/adress web API and widget

Tags: plugins, web, dictionary

I'm looking for some sort of plugin or API with which I can use map functionality on my website. It should be able to perform the following actions:

1. Locating a postal code or other address information inputted by users.
2. Calculating the distance between to location.
3. (Similar to previous point) Generate a list of the nearest saved locations (in a database) from a location inputted by a user.
4. Display locations on a map.

Now this obviously looks very similar to what Google Maps can do, and that was the first place I looked. Google has a lot of plugins but none of them seem to fit my needs.

Am I overlooking a Google Maps plugin or is there another good API/plugin I could use (preferably free of course)?

In case it's relevant: I'm mainly using PHP and JS with the CodeIgniter framework.

Thanks in advance!